# how to set background for a TextView with compound drawable?

Tags: android, textview, imagebutton

As follows, I have a TextView with compound drawable, and want to set android:background for the compound drawable(not for the whole TextView), so when pressing the compound drawable, it will behave like an ImageButton. what can I do, any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.iclinux.android.custom_views.NoScrollTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:iclinux="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/search_engine_item"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_bg"
    style="@style/EllipsizedSingleLineTextView"
    android:textSize="@dimen/grid_item_title_size"
    >
</com.iclinux.android.custom_views.NoScrollTextView>
```

Comment: You don't want it to behave like an image button? or do you want it to? Clarify yourself. It's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks, I want it to behave like an ImageButton.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use an `imagebutton`?

Comment: You can set a state list drawable rather than the icon directly

Comment: thanks, but it seems that I can't setCompoundDrawables() with a state list drawable, only setBackgroundDrawable() works. what I meant is set background for the compound drawable, not the whole textview.